# file path/url in file entity tpl

Tags: 7, theming, files

I have a tpl file for file entities of type image: file--image.tpl.php.

In this file I use `$file_url` to get the url of the file. But I'm not sure if this is correct. This Drupal installation we have in a subfolder of the www-root. If the subfolder is http://ourserver/dev I get /dev/img_file_name.jpg as url for the image. But it should be only img_file_name.jpg.

How can I get the correct url of the image?

All other fields of the file entity are working as expected.

Comment: $content['file']['#markup'] does it

Comment: Oh, not really in my case.

In Structure » file types » image » manage file display with set 'URL to file' it works. But I need to set 'Image URL' to be able to set the image style. In this case $content['file']['#markup'] does not work. How can I get the image URL in file_entity.tpl.php with set 'Image URL' as output mode?